# read.csv() error: more columns than column names

Tags: r, csv, read.csv

I'm trying to input a CSV file, but I get the following error:

```
associatedata <- read.csv("AssociatedSpeciesID_1.csv", header=TRUE, fileEncoding = 'UTF-8-BOM') %>% mutate_all(na_if, "")

Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  more columns than column names
```

Here's the CSV below: I can't find where the number of columns doesn't matched up. I've tried common solutions to other questions, but nothing's worked.

```
ObjectID,GlobalID,AssociatedSpeciesKnown,Associates,NewAssociate,UnknownSpecies_Description,AssociatedSpeciesAbundance,Coflowering,ParentGlobalID,CreationDate,Creator,EditDate,Editor
1,54e33e7c-1ff1-464f-8872-df027fcfe8ec,known,Amelanchier utahensis,,,Few,no,9fc6b840-8584-4045-b69f-f0e9488a1f06,1/7/2022 3:55:46 PM,ejob_BLM,1/7/2022 3:55:46 PM,ejob,,
2,68420bc9-d6c6-4d7f-a149-7306399ce5c1,known,NewSpecies,Genus species,,Occasional,yes,9fc6b840-8584-4045-b69f-f0e9488a1f06,1/7/2022 3:55:46 PM,ejob_BLM,1/7/2022 3:55:46 PM,ejob,,
3,88a6807b-b00c-4e58-84bb-4e8cb61409ae,unknown,,,ritiidiwjjviern bg,Common,no,9fc6b840-8584-4045-b69f-f0e9488a1f06,1/7/2022 3:55:46 PM,ejob_BLM,1/7/2022 3:55:46 PM,ejob,,
4,9fc8ea4a-e197-42cc-bd75-614d5b106364,known,Artemisia nova,,,Common,no,ea9eb086-89c2-4aa5-a2f6-95519cd35a58,1/7/2022 3:56:26 PM,ejob_BLM,1/7/2022 3:56:26 PM,ejob,,
```

Comment: Without having actually looked at it, I'm going to guess that there is a space somewhere. Have you tried setting `check.names = F`? It might come in wacky, but it will help narrow down the issue.

Comment: not sure why the error is caused, but may be you can try other package like `read_csv()` from `tidyverse`, not entirely sure if that would help but could be worth a try

Comment: @monte No luck there.

Comment: @Kat No luck, still get the same error. Do spaces in the field values matter? Because there are spaces there.

Comment: Whitespace can definitely make a difference. You could try `header = F, skip = 1` and then read in just line one for the headings (`nrow = 1`). Does that work?

Comment: @Kat That still produces an error, but it works when i try header=F, skip=1 and then read in a handmade vector with the column headers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The header has 13 fields and all other records have 15 and examining it we see that there are two trailing commas on the end of each data line.

```
count.fields("abc.csv", sep = ",")
## [1] 13 15 15 15 15
```

**1)** If we remove the two trailing commas then it works.  (You may not need the strip.white but it was added because the code in the Note at the end is indented 4 spaces to satisfy SO. It won't hurt.)

```
L <- "abc.csv" |>
  readLines() |>
  sub(pattern = ",,$", replacement = "")
DF <- read.csv(text = L, strip.white = TRUE)
```

giving

```
> str(DF)
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  13 variables:
 $ ObjectID                  : int  1 2 3 4
 $ GlobalID                  : chr  "54e33e7c-1ff1-464f-8872-df027fcfe8ec" "68420bc9-d6c6-4d7f-a149-7306399ce5c1" "88a6807b-b00c-4e58-84bb-4e8cb61409ae" "9fc8ea4a-e197-42cc-bd75-614d5b106364"
 $ AssociatedSpeciesKnown    : chr  "known" "known" "unknown" "known"
 $ Associates                : chr  "Amelanchier utahensis" "NewSpecies" "" "Artemisia nova"
 $ NewAssociate              : chr  "" "Genus species" "" ""
 $ UnknownSpecies_Description: chr  "" "" "ritiidiwjjviern bg" ""
 $ AssociatedSpeciesAbundance: chr  "Few" "Occasional" "Common" "Common"
 $ Coflowering               : chr  "no" "yes" "no" "no"
 $ ParentGlobalID            : chr  "9fc6b840-8584-4045-b69f-f0e9488a1f06" "9fc6b840-8584-4045-b69f-f0e9488a1f06" "9fc6b840-8584-4045-b69f-f0e9488a1f06" "ea9eb086-89c2-4aa5-a2f6-95519cd35a58"
 $ CreationDate              : chr  "1/7/2022 3:55:46 PM" "1/7/2022 3:55:46 PM" "1/7/2022 3:55:46 PM" "1/7/2022 3:56:26 PM"
 $ Creator                   : chr  "ejob_BLM" "ejob_BLM" "ejob_BLM" "ejob_BLM"
 $ EditDate                  : chr  "1/7/2022 3:55:46 PM" "1/7/2022 3:55:46 PM" "1/7/2022 3:55:46 PM" "1/7/2022 3:56:26 PM"
 $ Editor                    : chr  "ejob" "ejob" "ejob" "ejob"
```

**2)** Alternately if sed is on your path then:

```
read.csv(pipe("sed -e s/,,$// abc.csv"), strip.white = TRUE)
```

**3)** This would also work.

```
DF <- read.csv("abc.csv", header = FALSE, skip = 1, strip.white = TRUE)[1:13]
names(DF) <- read.table("abc.csv", sep = ",", strip.white = TRUE, nrows = 1)
```

### Note

Generate file from question.

```
Lines <- "ObjectID,GlobalID,AssociatedSpeciesKnown,Associates,NewAssociate,UnknownSpecies_Description,AssociatedSpeciesAbundance,Coflowering,ParentGlobalID,CreationDate,Creator,EditDate,Editor
1,54e33e7c-1ff1-464f-8872-df027fcfe8ec,known,Amelanchier utahensis,,,Few,no,9fc6b840-8584-4045-b69f-f0e9488a1f06,1/7/2022 3:55:46 PM,ejob_BLM,1/7/2022 3:55:46 PM,ejob,,
2,68420bc9-d6c6-4d7f-a149-7306399ce5c1,known,NewSpecies,Genus species,,Occasional,yes,9fc6b840-8584-4045-b69f-f0e9488a1f06,1/7/2022 3:55:46 PM,ejob_BLM,1/7/2022 3:55:46 PM,ejob,,
3,88a6807b-b00c-4e58-84bb-4e8cb61409ae,unknown,,,ritiidiwjjviern bg,Common,no,9fc6b840-8584-4045-b69f-f0e9488a1f06,1/7/2022 3:55:46 PM,ejob_BLM,1/7/2022 3:55:46 PM,ejob,,
4,9fc8ea4a-e197-42cc-bd75-614d5b106364,known,Artemisia nova,,,Common,no,ea9eb086-89c2-4aa5-a2f6-95519cd35a58,1/7/2022 3:56:26 PM,ejob_BLM,1/7/2022 3:56:26 PM,ejob,,
"
cat(Lines, file = "abc.csv")
```